# variables of an under function can't be read with the global function

Tags: node.js

I have an under function in an other global function. I want that one variable of the small function be read with the global one, so I can use this variable in my code everywhere.

```
function name() {
   getline('./STT.txt', 4, function(err, line) {
   var str = line;
   var obj = str.substr(11);
   var pathfile = path.resolve('/home/pi/Desktop', obj);
});
```

So I want `pathfile to be accessible everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

To access the `pathfile` variable globally, Instead of declaring the variables inside the function, you should **declare the variables outside the function and assign the values inside the function.**

```
var pathfile = '';
function name() {
    getline('./STT.txt', 4, function(err, line) {
      var str = line;
      var obj = str.substr(11);
      pathfile = path.resolve('/home/pi/Desktop', obj);
  });
```

Comment: I try this but the value of pathfile does not change

Comment: can you share me the full code, and where did you use the path file. please share your full code. so that we can help you surely.

Comment: I started with just this then i will add other functions where i would like to use pathfile